# the number guessing game

Tags: javascript

Ok I have almost everything done beside write a timeout that asks users if they want to stop the game if they do not press the Guess button within 10 seconds. If the user selects OK, close the Web browser window.I can not figure it out this is what i have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Guess the number</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS
hiddenNumber = Math.round((Math.random() * 100))%100 + 1;
function checkGuess(obj) {
    var status;
    var guess=obj.value;
    if (guess > hiddenNumber) {
        status=(guess+" is Too high!\nTry again");
    }
    else if (guess < hiddenNumber) {
        status=(guess+" is Too low!\nTry again");
    }
    else if (guess == hiddenNumber){
        status=("Congratulations! You guessed the number!\n"+guess);
    }
    alert(status);
    obj.value='';
}
function continueGame(){
    var quit = confirm("Do you want to stop playing?");
    if (quit == true)
        window.close();
}
// STOP HIDING FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS -->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Guessing Game</H1>
Guess a number between 1 - 100:
<FORM NAME="guessForm">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="guessField">
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE=" Guess "
onClick="checkGuess(document.guessForm.guessField);">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: @AtesGoral: Thanks, beat me to it.

Comment: Um, you have the xhtml 1.0 strict DTD and all your tags are in ALL CAPS which is illegal in xhtml. Also, really bad style in HTML. And that <!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS stuff hasn't been necessary for 10 years. And it's also illegal in xhtml. I don't mean to be too critical, but I thought you'd want to know.

Comment: Well thanks for letting me know we are being tough to use the <!-- hide part with the xhtml..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timeout=setTimeout(checkExit,10*1000);

if (/*pressed on guess*/)
{
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout=setTimeout(checkExit,10*1000);
}

function checkExit()
{
   if (confirm("Exit?")) window.close();
   else //reset timeout here again
}
```

Comment: Ok i must be doing something wrong when i add this in when i type in a number it doesnt work.

Comment: this is not a working code! its just a template. read comments

Answer (score 0):

If you add this in your code, after ten seconds the continueGame() function will run:

```
var t = setTimeout("continueGame()",10000);
```

Comment: Avoid the string form. You can directly pass in the function: `setTimeout(continueGame, 10000);

Comment: It should probably noted that passing the function directly will only work if there are no arguments to pass to the function. If there were arguments then you would have to use the string version. I'm sure that could be quite confusing to someone who appears to be learning Javascript. Besides there is nothing really wrong with the string version, just a little slower.

Comment: @New Guy: Only if the arguments were literals or globals (eww!). There's really not a compelling excuse for using the string form.

Comment: yes i understand something but i am still at the beginning of javascript.